# DPDK Error in Transmitting/Receiving packets

Tags: c, latency, dpdk

I have a application running with 2 cores on each port. If I use lid type as RX_TYPE on both the ports and run a application it works fine by transmitting and receiving udp packets. But if I use lid type as TX_TYPE on the ports I could able to transmit packets but not able receive the packets. why ?

I am using DPDK 19.11.10

Basically I am try to calculate latency between two ports and vice-versa.
I am running my application as below

```
./send_udp -c 0xff -n 4 -- -m [2:3].0,[4:5].1,
```

Here is my sample code

```
void send_udp_pkt(int portid)
{
 struct rte_mbuf      *pkts[DEFAULT_PKT_BURST+1] = { };/*DEFAULT_PKT_BURST is 32*/
 while(1){
  /*build udp pkt and trasmit*/
  rte_eth_tx_burst(portid, queueid, pkts, cnt);
  
  /*Receive udp pkt and process*/
  rte_eth_rx_burst(portid, queueid, pkts, 32);
  }
}

int rxtx_loop(__attribute__ ((unused)) void * arg)
{
  if (lid_type == TX_TYPE){
    if(portid == 0)
      send_udp_pkt(portid);
    else if (portid == 1)
      send_udp_pkt(portid);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  rte_eal_init(argc, argv);

  config_ports();

  for (i = 0; i < RTE_MAX_LCORE; i++ ) {
    if ( (i == rte_get_main_lcore()) || !rte_lcore_is_enabled(i) )
            continue;
    switch(get_type(i)) {/*get_type function will get lid type same as in pkt gen*/
            case RX_TYPE:
            case TX_TYPE:
                ret = rte_eal_remote_launch(rxtx_loop, NULL, i);
                break;
    }
}
rte_eal_mp_wait_lcore();

    return 0;
}
```

The above code snippet will work properly if I use `lid_type == RX_TYPE` in `rxtx_loop` function.

What might be the issue? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: please share your port configuration and how you did it. And which params you actually  passed in rte_eth_rx_burst() and rte_eth_tx_burst()

Comment: @NafiulAlamFuji I have updated the params passing in rte_eth_rx_burst() and rte_eth_tx_burst(). Can you mention what exactly you are looking in port configuration?

Comment: whats inside your get_type() funtion? please put logs and check the values for "i vs get_type(i)" and also check every enabled core status through log. I think the problem lies in your logic as the code flow seems pretty simple and should work anyway for "TX_TYPE" if works for "RX_TYPE". you should first check milestone after milestone whether the code flow is working properly or not.